# Get interpolated 2D matrix by interpolating layers of 3D matrix in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, interpolation

I have a 3D matrix defined like so:

```
A = zeros(3,3,3)*3;
A(:,:,1) = [1 2 3; 3 2 1; 3 4 7];
A(:,:,2) = [4 5 6; 6 5 4; 2 5 8];
A(:,:,3) = [7 8 9; 9 8 7; 3 6 9];
```

My goal is to extract a 2D matrix by interpolating 2 consecutive layers of the 3D matrix. In this example i want the matrix at a 75% distance between layer 1 and 2. I was able to achieve this by doing a simple linear interpolation but I would like to get some better and smarter way to perform this task maybe taking advantage of the built-in Matlab functions.

```
l = 1; % Layer: 1<= l <= size(A,3)-1
x = 0.75; % Distance at which i want to interpolate from layer 0<= x <= 1
AMin = A(:,:,l);
AMax = A(:,:,l+1);

AMin + (AMax-AMin)*x
```

Which returns

```
3.25         4.25         5.25
5.25         4.25         3.25
2.25         4.75         7.75
```

as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`interp3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp3.html), but your code is clearer and probably faster:

```
x = 1.75; % interpolate between 3rd-dim layers 1 and 2, closer to 2
result = interp3(A, 1:size(A,2), (1:size(A,1)).', x);
```

Note that the second and third arguments to `interp3` here are a row and a column vector. This selects all values of each 3rd-dim layer, because, from the documentation,

> `Vq = interp3(V,Xq,Yq,Zq)`
>
> If `Xq`, `Yq`, and `Zq` are vectors of different orientations, then `Xq`, `Yq`, and `Zq` are treated as grid vectors in R<sup>3</sup>.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you need `1:size(A,2), (1:size(A,1)).'` (x is the 2nd index, y is the first).

Answer (score 3):

The built-in function `interp3` can do what you're looking for.

```
A = zeros(3,3,3)*3;
A(:,:,1) = [1 2 3; 3 2 1; 3 4 7];
A(:,:,2) = [4 5 6; 6 5 4; 2 5 8];
A(:,:,3) = [7 8 9; 9 8 7; 3 6 9];

X = 0:size(A,1)-1;
Y = 0:size(A,2)-1;

[XX,YY] = meshgrid(X,Y); % 2D grid - so we can evaluate at many points
Target_Z = 0.75 * ones(size(XX));

OUT = interp3(X,Y,Z,A,XX,YY,Target_Z);
```

The output would be

```
OUT =
    3.2500    5.2500    2.2500
    4.2500    4.2500    4.7500
    5.2500    3.2500    7.7500
```

Of course, you don't have to pick a regular grid to evaluate this function. You could easily have selected any (x,y,z) triples to evaluate.

Comment: Don't transpose the output of the interpolation, instead use `meshgrid`, or change the input of `ndgrid` so it's not transposed: `[XX,YY]=meshgrid(X,Y)` or `[YY,XX]=ndgrid(Y,X)`.

Comment: Originally I had used ndgrid to make 3D XX,YY, ZZ blocks but I didn't need them. I've always been annoyed meshgrid and ndgrid aren't the same orientation.

Comment: Indeed, it's annoying. :)